# Arch GLIBC_2.33 not found errors after updating one package

Tags: arch-linux, glibc, pacman

I ran

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

...saw all the packages needing download and backed out.  Then I ran

```
sudo pacman -S openssl
```

to update just that package, and it succeeded.  Now, I can't do much of anything else.  Biggest problem is even pacman won't run.

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/cache/pacman/pkg/openssl*
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: unable to load /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
```

then

```
# pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/openssl-1.1.1.i-2-x86-64.pkg.tar.zst
pacman: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
```

There are only 11 lines in /var/log/pacman.log from these operations.  After the successful update of openssl from 1.1.1.i-2 -> 1.1.1.j-1, the last three lines are:

```
[ALPM] running 'clean_package_cache.hook'...
[ALPM-SCRIPTLET] pacman-conf: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
[ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> no candidte packages found for pruning
```

I'm concerned about rebooting the system, as I feel pretty sure it will be unsuccessful and I may have an easier time backing out of this if I have some guidance.  I found some information [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1956920) which seems it may be relevant, but I was hoping I wouldn't need to go to quite those lengths since the system is still booted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a live image of archlinux, install it to a usb and boot it.

Then mount your old root partition to /mnt/old_root with

```
mkdir /mnt/old_root
mount /dev/sdX2 /mnt/old_root
```

where /dev/sdX2 is the root partition. Check with `lsblk` command beforehand.

Then type

```
pacstrap /mnt/old_root glibc lib32-glibc
```

This will install newest version of glibc in your system. You can restart now and the errors should have gone.

On a side note, archlinux(and it's derivatives) don't support partial upgrades. i.e upgrading one package without upgrading others. Please read this link:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported

I can confirm this works because i just did this .

Answer (score 1):

Solution if host has docker:

1. Run archlinux container wich root volume:

```bsh
docker run -it -v /:/tmp/hostroot archlinuxrolling/pacman bash
```

2. Update glibc within container

```bsh
pacman -S -r /tmp/hostroot glibc lib32-glibc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after updating pacman only. I wanted to fix the issue without rebooting.

I also didn't have docker installed, as mentioned by [@Sergey](https://superuser.com/a/1630246/120051).

The error messages were similar to:

```
pacman: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by pacman)
pacman: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.13)
```

And,

```
pacman-conf: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by pacman-conf)
pacman-conf: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.13)
```

So I found the [pacman-static](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pacman-static) AUR package that provides a statically linked version of pacman. I tried to build it, but the build process requires a working `pacman-conf`, which I also didn't have. (I describe this process further below, but it's not needed for the solution.) There was a [pre-built binary version of pacman-static for x86_64](https://pkgbuild.com/%7Emorganamilo/pacman-static/x86_64/bin/) provided by the package author, which did work.

I used this pre-built pacman-static binary to upgrade the `glibc` package.

```
$ gpg --verify pacman-static.sig pacman-static
$ gpg --recv-keys F850562FCDA369F80D33000AE48D0A8326DE47C5
$ gpg --verify pacman-static.sig pacman-static
$ chmod +x pacman-static
$ sudo su
# ./pacman-static -Sy
# ./pacman-static -S glibc
```

**This fixed the original issue**, and after this the normal `pacman` and `pacman-conf` started to work. But now I need to upgrade the entire system, since everything else depends on glibc.

```
pacman -Syu
```

(Alternatively, I could try downgrading the `pacman` package to an earlier version (and skip upgrading the glibc package and the rest of the system), it's possible at this point, but I won't try it now.)

.

---

.

## Building the `pacman-static` package (not needed for the fix above)

I didn't finish building the pacman-static package from source, but this is as far as I got:

It requires the `devtools` package, which must be built from source if not already installed. (Since pacman is unavailable)

https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/devtools/-/releases/

There seems to be a pre-built version of the `devtools` package too. The latest one I downloaded is:

https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/devtools/-/releases/v1.0.4/downloads/devtools-1.0.4.tar.gz.sig
https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/devtools/-/releases/v1.0.4/downloads/devtools-1.0.4.tar.gz

```
$ gpg --verify devtools-1.0.4.tar.gz.sig devtools-1.0.4.tar.gz
$ gpg --recv-keys E240B57E2C4630BA768E2F26FC1B547C8D8172C8
$ gpg --verify devtools-1.0.4.tar.gz.sig devtools-1.0.4.tar.gz
```

The `devtools` Makefile requires the `asciidoc` package for generating the documentation, which I didn't have, so I commented out the parts that require asciidoc. I could build and install the `devtools` package successfully after that.

In the devtools **Makefile** comment out the line:

```
@a2x --no-xmllint --asciidoc-opts="-f doc/asciidoc.conf" -d manpage -f manpage --destination-dir=$(BUILDDIR)/doc/man -a pkgdatadir=$(DATADIR) $<
```

And also comment out these 3 lines:

```
for manfile in $(MANS); do \
    install -Dm644 $$manfile -t $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man$${manfile##*.}; \
done;
```

After that build and install it with:

```
$ make binprogs library conf completion
$ sudo su
# make install
```

This installs the **extra-x86_64-build** symlink to `archbuild`, which is used by the `pacman-static` build script (**build-packages.sh**).
(But that requires a working `pacman-conf`...)

Since there was no static version of `pacman-conf` available, I didn't get further than that.