# Pacman and Arch Linux - No longer booting due to package issues, glibc

Tags: boot, arch-linux, packages, glibc, pacman

After having some pacman issues, I am not longer able to boot into my arch linux systemafter grub. All I get is a black screen without the ability to input anything. I believe this is due to accidentally removing the base-devel package and possibly having previous pacman issues I was unaware of.

**What happened:**
I was trying to install PHP for a take home project I'm doing for an interview process. I used
`sudo pacman -S php`
and several other variants with different versions, but I always received an error. I forget which error it was, but I believe I got the message that it could not recognize the package. This was the first package I've attempted to install in some months, so I'm unsure if I had pacman issues beforehand or if they just surfaced now. Anyway, I decided to test if it was a pacman issue or some issue with the php package itself. So, I naively thought, "I'll try downloading some random package other than PHP to see if it works, then remove it if it does download since I don't care about it anyway." I was dumb and googled something along of the lines of "cool arch packages" and saw someone mention that **base-devel** was cool. So, I decided to install it. It worked! Or so I think? Either it worked, or it was already on my system, so I thought it worked since I didn't read the output too closely. Since I thought I didn't need the package I presumably downloaded as a pacman test, I ran
`sudo pacman -R base-devel`
to not have that space taken up and everything went south. I assume this is some foundational package and I destroyed my computer. Afterwards, pacman really stopped working altogether. I received an error relating to glibc and lib32-glibc not being found and pacman wouldn't run. I tried other things like using a hotkey to open a terminal and opening nemo, but neither worked. It was at this point I realized, I f***ed up. Now, when I boot my computer, after grub, I just get a black screen with no way to input anything.

**What I've attempted:**

**1.** I'm currently booting through a live USB trying to find a way to get things to work. I am mounting my partition to /mnt and trying to repair pacman. I've consulted this link for help: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Pacman_crashes_during_an_upgrade
and have tried the following:

`mount /dev/sdaX /mnt`

`mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc; mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys; mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev`

`pacman --sysroot /mnt -Syu`

When I do this last step, I get

> error: failed retrieving file 'community.db' from : Could not resolve host:

I plugged in an ethernet cable and do have internet, as I've used ping successfully.
Where I mounted, my /etc was empty, so copied pacman from the live USB onto my mounted partition to try to use it. It still didn't work, so I thought maybe I had an issue with the mirrors.
I followed this link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors
After including US mirrors above the Include lines in pacman.conf, I tried running
`pacman -Syyu`
as the page mentions and it does look like things downloaded. But, I still have failures retrieving "linux-firmware-20210315...pkg.tar.zst" and "logrotate-3.18.0...pkg.tar.zst". I don't know if my mirrors are out of date or if there is another issue. After this, I've run
`pacman --sysroot /mnt -Syu`
again, but I still get

> error: failed retrieving file 'community.db' from : Could not resolve host:

**2.** Another thing I tried was from this link: [Arch GLIBC_2.33 not found errors after updating one package](https://superuser.com/questions/1628582/arch-glibc-2-33-not-found-errors-after-updating-one-package)
I mounted my partition to /mnt, then ran
`pacstrap /mnt glibc lib32-glibc`
The output of this is:

> ==>Creating install root at /mnt

> mount: /mnt/proc: proc already mounted on /proc.

> ==>Error: failed to setup chroot /mnt

I am (obviously) by no means an experienced user, so I don't even know if I am remotely on the right track with either of these approaches, but I'd love your input on this issue and would be grateful for anyone's time and wisdom. I actually have 4 job interviews this week and 2 onsites coming up, so I need to reverse my dimwittedness and hope to resolve this problem before it's too late haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using the steps in this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/mby9ts/no_longer_booting_due_to_package_issues_glibc/gs4pkfs?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

The exact details are above. In summary, I did the below.

What I had to do was make a fresh live USB, mount my root partition, update my mirrors, update my broken packages using `pacstrap` along with base, linux, and linux-firmware (not sure if this last part was necessary or not, maybe?), then arch-chroot into my mounted root partition. Once there, I ran `pacman -Syu` which gave me an error due to npm. I uninstalled npm, ran `pacman -Syu`, and reinstalled npm and everything worked! The key for me was getting the latest version of arch on my live USB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you removed the *GlibC* package (and while you were doing it, you deleted all it's dependencies, on which most packages depend) because some packages included in the *base-devel* group depend on *GlibC*, therefore you removed almost all packages, the only option left would be to **reinstall completely**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I don't recall removing the **glibc** package. However, I did, without thinking, remove **base-devel**. Would that also get rid of glibc somehow? If there is no other option, is there a way pacman or my system could have been cached,or is completely reinstalling the only way to go? I found others with the glibc issue I described and they were able to resolve it, though I haven't been able to replicate what they did.

Comment: Just to add some links of what I found regarding **glibc:**
This person fixed it with pacstrap though I get a chroot error: [link]https://superuser.com/questions/1628582/arch-glibc-2-33-not-found-errors-after-updating-one-package[/link]
This person updated pacman, though I haven't been able to: [link]https://forum.manjaro.org/t/usr-lib-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-33-not-found/52914[/link]
And here are a couple others:
[link]https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1956920[/link]
[link]https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/lz7777/pacman_broken_due_to_glibc/[/link]